# Excluding tags from results using Querybuilder

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr

AEM allows me to query against a REST API like so:

> Search for pages tagged with a certain tag
>
> http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?type=cq:Page&tagid=marketing:interest/product&tagid.property=jcr:content/cq:tags
>
> ```
> 1 type=cq:Page
> 2 tagid=marketing:interest/product
> 3 tagid.property=jcr:content/cq:tags
> ```

However what if I want all pages that don't include a certain tag?

```
 1 type=cq:Page
 2 tagid=marketing:interest/product
 3 tagid.property=jcr:content/cq:tags
```

In xPath I can do something like:

```
//jcr:content/cq:tags[not(@tagId = 'marketing:interest/product')]
```

Is this possible through the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
path=/content/some/path/you/need
type=cq:Page
group.1_fulltext=marketing:interest/product
group.1_fulltext.relPath=jcr:content/@cq:tags
group.p.not=true
```

what correpsonds to next xpath query:

`/jcr:root/content/some/path/you/need//element(*, cq:Page) [ not(jcr:contains (jcr:content/@cq:tags, 'marketing:interest/product')c) ]`.

Also you can add `p.limit=[some number]` to get more than 10 results.

Some interesting info you can find [there](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.html) and [more about available predicates](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PredicateEvaluator.html) (check implementing classes).

Answer (score 0):

I tried `/jcr:root/content/geometrixx//element(*, cq:Page)[(jcr:content/@cq:template != '/apps/geometrixx/templates/contentpage') ]`

It gives me pages under `/content/geometrixx` which do not use template path `/apps/geometrixx/templates/contentpage`

Comment: Can you post this as a JSON QueryBuilder Link?

Comment: Yes I will look to try something like `tagid.property!=jcr:content/cq:tags`  itself. Does using ! work for you?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me - AFAIK != with xpath unless wrapped like so `degree[@from != "Harvard"]` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx